# Double Sms issue in my Php Sms API

Tags: php

I've a Php SMS API which send SMS to my client. All is OK right now but it's send 2 sms once i submit the form. I can't understand why it's send 2 SMS. Can you guys tell me why its send 2 sms ?

**Api Code:**

```
<?php 
class Sender{ 
var $host; 
var $port; 
/* 
* Username that is to be used for submission 
*/ 
var $strUserName; 
/* 
* password that is to be used along with username 
*/ 
var $strPassword; 
/* 
* Sender Id to be used for submitting the message 
*/ 
var $strSender; 
/* 
* Message content that is to be transmitted 
*/ 
var $strMessage; 
/* 
* Mobile No is to be transmitted. 
*/ 
var $strMobile; 
/* 
* What type of the message that is to be sent 
* <ul> 
* <li>0:means plain text</li> 
* <li>1:means flash</li> 
* <li>2:means Unicode (Message content should be inHex)</li> 
* <li>6:means Unicode Flash (Message content shouldbe in Hex)</li> 
* </ul> 
*/ 
var $strMessageType; 
/* 
* Require DLR or not 
* <ul> 
* <li>0:means DLR is not Required</li> 
* <li>1:means DLR is Required</li> 
* </ul> 
*/ 
var $strDlr; 
private function sms__unicode($message){ 
$hex1=''; 
if (function_exists('iconv')) { 
$latin = @iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', $message); 
if (strcmp($latin, $message)) { 
$arr = unpack('H*hex', @iconv('UTF-8', 'UCS-2BE', $message)); 
$hex1 = strtoupper($arr['hex']); 
} 
if($hex1 ==''){ 
$hex2=''; 
$hex=''; 
for ($i=0; $i < strlen($message); $i++){ 
$hex = dechex(ord($message[$i])); 
$len =strlen($hex); 
$add = 4 - $len; 
if($len < 4){ 
for($j=0;$j<$add;$j++){ 
$hex="0".$hex; 
} 
} 
$hex2.=$hex; 
} 
return $hex2; 
} 
else{ 
return $hex1; 
} 
} 
else{ 
print 'iconv Function Not Exists !'; 
} 
} 
//Constructor.. 
public function Sender ($host,$port,$username,$password, $sender, $message,   
$mobile,$msgtype,$dlr){ 
$this->host=$host; 
$this->port=$port; 
$this->strUserName = $username; 
$this->strPassword = $password; 
$this->strSender= $sender; 
$this->strMessage=$message; //URL Encode The Message.. 
$this->strMobile=$mobile; 
$this->strMessageType=$msgtype; 
$this->strDlr=$dlr; 
} 

public function Submit(){ 
if($this->strMessageType=="2" || 
$this->strMessageType=="6") { 
//Call The Function Of String To HEX. 
$this->strMessage = $this->sms__unicode( 
$this->strMessage); 
try{ 
//Smpp http Url to send sms. 
$live_url="http://".$this->host.":".$this->port."/bulksms 
/bulksms?username=".$this->strUserName."&password=".$this->strPassword."&  
type=".$this->strMessageType."&dlr=".$this->strDlr."&destination=".$this->strMobile."&
source=".$this->strSender."&message=".$this->strMessage.""; 
$parse_url=file($live_url); 
//echo $parse_url[0]; 
}catch(Exception $e){ 
//echo 'Message:' .$e->getMessage(); 
} 
} 
else 
$this->strMessage=urlencode($this->strMessage); 
try{ 
//Smpp http Url to send sms. 
$live_url="http://".$this->host.":". 
$this->port."/bulksms/bulksms?username=".$this->strUserName."&password=".$this->strPassword."&
type=".$this->strMessageType."&dlr=".$this->strDlr."&destination=".$this->strMobile."&
source=".$this->strSender."&message=".$this->strMessage.""; 
$parse_url=file($live_url); 
//echo $parse_url[0]; 
} 
catch(Exception $e){ 
//echo 'Message:' .$e->getMessage(); 
} 
} 
} 

//Call The Constructor. 
$obj = new Sender("mywebserver","myport","username","password","sender name", "my message",    
"mobile number","2","1"); 
$obj->Submit();      
?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to put the routine in case of "else" in braces. it should be like:

```
else {
    $this->strMessage=urlencode( $this->strMessage ); 
    try { 
      //Smpp http Url to send sms. 
      $live_url = "http://".$this->host . ":" . 
      $this->port."/bulksms/bulksms?username = ".$this->strUserName."&password=".$this->strPassword."&
      type = ".$this->strMessageType."&dlr=".$this->strDlr."&destination=".$this->strMobile."&
      source = ".$this->strSender."&message=".$this->strMessage.""; 
      $parse_url = file( $live_url ); 
      //echo $parse_url[0]; 
    } catch( Exception $e ) { 
      //echo 'Message:' .$e->getMessage(); 
    }
}
```

Note the braces for "else".